# What is the strategy to finding $\sum_{k=2}^{300} k^k \pmod 7$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am stuck on this modular arithmetic problem for homework practice: 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{300} k^k \pmod 7$$

I am not quite sure how to approach this problem. I've tried finding a pattern between the sums but i do not think there is one. I know how to find mods of a^b (mod c) but for this question i am clueless. Any hints and help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does repeat, but only after $7*6 = 42$ terms (the bases repeat in cycles of 7 while the exponents repeat in cycles of 6).  Try breaking it up like this
$$\sum_{k=1}^{43} 1^{1 + 7(k-1)} + \sum_{k=1}^{43} 2^{2+7(k-1)} + \sum_{k=1}^{43} 3^{3+7(k-1)} + \sum_{k=1}^{43} 4^{4+7(k-1)} + \sum_{k=1}^{43} 5^{5+7(k-1)} + \sum_{k=1}^{43} 6^{6+7(k-1)} + \sum_{k=1}^{42} 7^{7+7(k-1)}$$
Now, the exponents can be reduced $\bmod{6}$, since $a^{6} \equiv 1 \bmod{7}$ for every $a \neq 0$. This gives
$$\sum_{k=1}^{43} \left( 1^{1 + (k-1)} +  2^{2+(k-1)} +  3^{3+(k-1)} +  4^{4+(k-1)} +  5^{5+(k-1)} +  6^{(k-1)}\right)$$
or equivalently
$$7\sum_{k=1}^{6} \left(1^{1 + (k-1)} +  2^{2+(k-1)} +  3^{3+(k-1)} +  4^{4+(k-1)} +  5^{5+(k-1)} +  6^{(k-1)}\right) + 1^{1} +  2^{2} +  3^{3} +  4^{4} +  5^{5} +  6^{0}$$

Answer (score 1):

For any $k$ there are integers $q,r$ such that $k=7q+r$ where $0\leq r\leq 6$.

So $$k^k=(7q+r)^{(7q+r)}\cong r^{(7q+r)}\quad (mod 7).$$

From you should use Fermat little theorem.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: But $9^9\not\equiv 2^2\pmod{7}$ though. Fermat little theorem only implies $x^6\equiv1\pmod{7}$.

Comment: Edit, thanks for comments, wasn't careful enough.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize what is below, basically $(x+42)^{x+42}\equiv x^x\pmod{7}$
and since $300=42\times7+6$ there are $7$ periods of same remainders plus 6 extra things so the remainder has to equal to the 6 extra things.

---

For writing convinience we denote $0^0=0$ in this anwer.

Now apply fermat little theorem $x^6\equiv1\pmod{7}$ we get your sum is congruent to

$$0^0+1^1+2^2+...+6^0+7^1+8^2+...+12^0+13^1+...299^5+300^0$$

which is congruent to

$$0^0+1^1+2^2+...+6^0+0^1+1^2+...+5^0+6^1+...5^5+6^0$$

We group each seven together:

$$(0^0+1^1+2^2+...+6^0)+(0^1+1^2+...+5^0+6^1)+...+(0^5+...+6^5)+...+(0^0+...+5^5+6^0)$$

Now every period consists of $6$ groups.

Now each "6-groups" have 42 elements and $300=42\cdot7+6$ so there are $7$ "6-group"s and your sum is congrent to $(0^0+1^1+2^2+3^3+4^4+5^5+6^0)\equiv 5\pmod{7}$